# react-datetime + set interval in React

Tags: reactjs, datetime, npm, react-datetime

I am using react-datetime control for npm package :[click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime).
In that time picker how should I set Interval. For example I want to set interval in every 5 minutes so first show 0 then 5,10,15 etc. how can I achive this?

I am using look like this but not working :

[image: Example]

Comment: look for  `timeConstraints` setting property

Comment: yes. means time picker set specific interval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timeConstraints` allows for custom step configuration, so, it should look like:

```js
  minutes: { step: 5 }
```

example:

```js
{
  timeConstraints = {
    minutes: {
      step: 5
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Datetime timeConstraints={this.timeConstraints} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: To add directly: timeConstraints = {{ minutes: { step: 15 }}}